# Python ndarray management

Tags: python, memory-management

I would like to know how does Python actually manages memory allocation for `ndarrays`.

I loaded a file that contains 32K floating value using numpy `loadtxt`, so the `ndarray` size should be 256KB data.

Actually, `ndarray.nbytes` gives the right size.

However, the memory occupation after loading data is increased by 2MB: I don't unserstand why this difference.

Comment: What do you mean by "the memory occupation" exactly?

Comment: the memory space occupied by the application

Comment: I suggest you to reword the question in the form of a [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure exactly how you measure memory occupation, but when looking at the memory footprint of your entire app there's a lot more that could be happening that causes these kind of memory occupation increases.

In this case, I suspect that the `loadtxt` function uses some buffering or otherwise copies the data which wasn't cleared yet by the GC.

But other things could be happening as well. Maybe the numpy back-end loads some extra stuff the first time it initialises a `ndarray`. Either way, you could only truly figure this stuff out by reading the numpy source could which is available freely on github. The implementation of `loadtxt` can be found here: https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/5b22ee427e17706e3b765cf6c65e924d89f3bfce/numpy/lib/npyio.py#L797

Comment: Thank you, i checked memory footprint using python memory profiler (mprof). I also read loadtxt code, i didn't help me a lot, because even if it actually does some extra processing, after its execution the memory occupation does not decrease